# How can I add a custom modeline and ignore EDID data?

Tags: display, screen, resolution

I have a [Samsung CRG90 Ultrawide Dual-QHD with 5120x1440 resolution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L9HCJ2V) that has [this modeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFree86_Modeline)

```
"5120x1440_60" 469 5120 5168 5200 5280 1440 1443 1453 1481 +HSync -Vsync
```

How can I force OSX to use this modeline and ignore EDID data. The EDID data that my [TESmart 4x4 hDMI Matrix is putting out doesn't support this mode line.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0854349RV) The HDMI Switch (and they all do this) provides dummy EDID data. It does this so the host OS that connects to the HDMI switch doesn't lose windows (the "scene") when the screen is active elsewhere and doesn't show as disconnected. In Linux, it's *very* easy to use `cvt` and `xrandr` to generate and add a mode line and **ignore the EDID data**. It's not clear how I can do that on OSX, or how I can mitigate bad EDID data coming from my switch.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  First, the modeline isn't part of the EDID, it's based off of it; usually created by the display server.  Where exactly do you want macOS to use this modeline and why?  EDID data describes what the device is capable of, so why are you attempting to override it?

Comment: I was very clear what I was trying to accomplish the EDID that is reported by my HDMI Switch (which I even linked to) is not correct. But here is more information: the switch (and they all do this) provides dummy EDID data. It does this so the host OS that connects to the HDMI switch doesn't lose windows. The problem is this EDID data is incorrect. In Linux, it's _very_ easy to use `cvt` and `xrandr` to generate and add a mode line and **ignore the EDID data**. It's not clear how I can do that on OSX, or how I can mitigate bad EDID data coming from my switch.

Comment: Well, `cvt` and `xrandr` are not "Linux" utilities per se.  They are tools used by Xorg because they are used by the X-Windowing system which macOS doesn't use; it uses Aqua.  Those tools take EDID data and create that modeline.  So, you can't take an Xorg convention and apply it to Aqua.  It's apples and oranges, here.

Comment: Try this [Github project](https://github.com/Akemi/macOS-edid-modification) to *modify* the EDID data.

Comment: Sure, I take your point nothing is "Linux" per se, except a kernel.

Comment: @Allan that github project requires root =( I don't have that. You can't add a custom resolution/modeline to OSX without root?

Comment: You’re modifying config files.  You *must* be root.  In macOS you don’t need to change video modes already configured. In X, it’s your session the display server is running so, root isn’t required.